# JQuery ajax post function is executed at the end of javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, post

i have a problem with validating if the username is already taken. I am trying to find out if the username already exists using the "post" method of jquery. But when executing this function, the script is always jumping to the end of the function and is doing the rest of the script first before executing the "post" command. Could you please review my code and help me?

```js
$("#submit").click(function () {

    var username = document.getElementById("username").value;
    var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
    var passwort = document.getElementById("passwort").value;
    var passwort2 = document.getElementById("passwort2").value;
    var validate = false;

    checkUsername();

    if (validate == true) {
        $.post("Login/register.php", {

            username: username,
            email: email,
            passwort: passwort,
            passwort2: passwort2,
        }, function (info) {
            $("#errorBox").empty();
            $("#errorBox").html(info);
        });

    } else {
        $('#register').submit(function () {
            return false;
        });
    }

    function checkUsername() {
        username = document.getElementById("username").value;
        // username = replaceUmlauts(username);
        if (username.length > 0) {
            document.getElementById("username").style.borderColor = "";
            // document.getElementById("errorBox").innerHTML =
            // "";
            validate = true;
            checkAvailability();
            return false;
        } else {
            document.getElementById("username").style.borderColor = "red";
            document.getElementById("errorBox").innerHTML = "Username muss länger als ein Zeichen sein";
            // alert('Username must be longer than one sign');
            validate = false;
            return false;
        }
    }

    function checkAvailability() {
        $.post(
            "Login/checkusername.php", {
                username: username
            },
            function (result) {
                // if the result is 1
                if (result == 1) {
                    // show that the username is
                    // available
                    document
                        .getElementById("errorBox").innerHTML = "";
                    return false;
                } else {
                    // show that the username is NOT
                    // available
                    document
                        .getElementById("errorBox").innerHTML = "Username nicht verfuegbar";
                    document
                        .getElementById("username").style.borderColor = "red";
                    validate = false;
                    return false;
                }
            });

    }
    return false;

});
```

edit: My html code :

```html
<form id="register" >
<div id='registerpopup'>
 <div class='close'></div>
 <span class='ecs_tooltip'>Schließen mit ESC<span class='arrow'></span></span>
 <div id='popup_content'> <!--your content start-->
  <table border=0 cellspacing=10 cellpadding=20 align=center>
  <div id="errorBox"></div>
   <tr>
   
    <th>
     <p style="margin-top: 20px; margin-right: 5px">Username:</p>
     <p style="margin-top: 18px; margin-right: 5px">E-Mail:<p>
     <p style="margin-top: 16px; margin-right: 5px">Passwort:</p>
     <p style="margin-top: 16px; margin-right: 5px">Passwort wdhl.:</p>
    </th>
    <th>
     <p style="margin-top: 20px"><input id="username" name="username"  type='text' size='30' maxlength='30' ><br></p>
     <p><input id="email" name="email" type='text' size='30' maxlength='30'><br></p>
     <p><input id="passwort" name="passwort"  type='password' size='30' maxlength='30' ><br></p>
     <p><input id="passwort2" name ="passwort2" type='password' size='30' maxlength='30'><br></p>
    </th>
   </tr>
  </table>
  <table border=0 cellspacing=10 cellpadding=20 align=center>
   <tr>
    <th>
     <button id="submit" class="submit" type="submit"  style="margin-top: 30px"> Registrieren </button>
    </th>
   </tr>
  </table>
 </div>
</div>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript" src ="js/checkregister.js"></script>

<div class='loader'></div>
<div id='backgroundPopup'></div>
```

I tried to change the `("#submit")` to `document.getElementById("submit")` to get my code "more clean" but it does not seem to work.

Comment: You shouldn't be mixing vanilla JS with JQuery unless absolutely necessary.

Comment: Can we see yout HTML as well?

Comment: If you use any jQuery, use it all! Your code will reduce to a third the size and be more readable.

Answer (score 0):

You have a scope issue with your variable `validate` , I suggest you this in your function `checkUsername()`:

```
if (username.length > 0) {
    document.getElementById("username").style.borderColor = "";
    // document.getElementById("errorBox").innerHTML =
    // "";
    return checkAvailability();
} else {
    document.getElementById("username").style.borderColor = "red";
    document.getElementById("errorBox").innerHTML = "Username muss länger als ein Zeichen sein";
    // alert('Username must be longer than one sign');
    return false;
}
```

, this in your function `checkAvailability()` :

```
if (result == 1) {
    // show that the username is
    // available
    document.getElementById("errorBox").innerHTML = "";
    return true;
} else {
    // show that the username is NOT
    // available
    document.getElementById("errorBox").innerHTML = "Username nicht verfuegbar";
    document.getElementById("username").style.borderColor = "red";
    return false;
}
```

and `var validate = checkUsername();` before your if statements in your main function

EDIT : This code is dirty, you should choose working with "old school JS" like `document.getElementById` for example, or jQuery (ex: `$('#myId')`), but the use of both is not recommanded

Comment: Wow! You are also using VanillaJS over jQuery.

Comment: I'm just pasting OP code to solve his issue, bad practices are another problem

Comment: Well, at least you're honest. Ha.

Comment: I editet my code like you said, but it is still not working, because my variable "validate" is undefinded when the username is longer than 0 and i try to return my checkAvailibility().

Comment: Could you please host your code on JSFiddle or plunkr for deeper debug ? I can't do much more without it

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/k3mdphd0/  Please let me know if you need any additional information

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough time to clean it all up, but this would be a good start. Pls note that I have used `$.post("/echo/html/", {` only for the demo purposes and commented the actual line as it wouldn't work in fiddle. Modify the code to suit your needs.

Demo@[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/caq0kwf9/)

```
$("#register").on("submit", function (evt) {

    evt.preventDefault();
    var $username = $("#username");
    var email = $.trim($("#email").val());
    var passwort = $.trim($("#passwort").val());
    var passwort2 = $.trim($("#passwort2").val());
    var $errorBox = $("#errorBox");
    var isUser = checkUsername();

    if (isUser) {
        checkAvailability();
    }

    function checkUsername() {
        var usernameVal = $.trim($username.val());
        if (usernameVal.length > 0) {
            $username.css({borderColor: "none"});
            return true;
        } else {
            $username.css({borderColor: "red"});
            $errorBox.html("Username muss länger als ein Zeichen sein");
        }
        return false;
    }

    function checkAvailability() {
        //$.post("Login/checkusername.php", {
        $.post("/echo/html/", {
            "username": $.trim($username.val())
        }, function (result) {
            // if the result is 1
            if (result == 1) {
                register().done(function() {
                    $errorBox.append("<p>Hurray!</p>");
                });
            } else {
                // show that the username is NOT
                // available
                $errorBox.html("Username nicht verfuegbar");
                $username.css({borderColor: "blue"});
                return;
            }
        });
    }

    function register() {
        //return $.post("Login/register.php", {
        return $.post("/echo/html/", {
            username: $.trim($username.val()),
            email: email,
            passwort: passwort,
            passwort2: passwort2,
        }, function (info) {
            $errorBox.html(info);
        });
    }
});
```